# Intellij IDEA: How can I format the code and how can I see the changes made?

Tags: intellij-idea

1. Cand I make the format code option to do something like this:

Before

```
int a = 1;





int b = 2;




return a+b;
```

After

```
int a = 1;
int b = 2;
return a+b;
```

Second Question:

I have a web app. I start the web app and after that, I made a change in a java file.

How can I see the change, without stoping and restarting the server - a shorter method?

Comment: Aaron, please ask one question at a time (per post, that is). Otherwise other users will find it hard to find it and especially the related answer.

Answer (score 0):

1. No, blank lines inside methods are not removed. Settings | Code Style | Blank Lines can control it in many places, but not within methods.
2. Easily, see the related [blog post](http://blogs.jetbrains.com/idea/2009/10/update-a-running-javaee-application/).